# Improving efficency in generating Tables with large numbers of values

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I'm simulating some transient data for fast Fourier transform -- on the order of 20 million points. Understandably MM takes a while to do this.

Are the any techniques in table generation optimisation when dealing with such large numbers? Or is this just a computational limit I have to accept?

This is my current attempt:

```
MyFunction[VMax_, Tau_, t_] := VMax Sin[2 Pi t] Exp[-t/Tau];
TransientData = Table[MyFunction[t],{t,0,60,3*10^-6}]
```

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'll add the function to make the question more complete. I wasn't sure how relevant the function would be.

Comment: Ping me when you are ready.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Ping. Typical values for `VMax = 1E-7`, `Tau = 400`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
VMax = 1. 10^-7;
Tau = 400.;
MyFunction[VMax_, Tau_, t_] := VMax Sin[2 Pi t] Exp[-t/Tau];
```

You exforce that a great part of the compuations is performed in exact arithmetic which is just slow.
Since the function `MyFunction` is built from elementary and vectorized functions, we may exploit that by *applying* it to the list instead of looping over it with `Table`. Here is a timing example; notice the introduction of decimal dots at critical positions:

```
n = 200000;
TransientData = Table[MyFunction[VMax, Tau, t], {t, 0, 60, 60/(n - 1)}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
TransientData1 = MyFunction[VMax, Tau, Subdivide[0., 60., n - 1]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

Max[Abs[TransientData - TransientData1]]
```

> 1.84223
>
> 0.004158
>
> 4.06758*10^-14

Comment: +1 There should be a space in the definition of `VMax`, i.e., `VMax=1. 10^-7` or use `VMax=10.^-7`

Comment: Good point @Bob. Thank you.